# Create column based on conditions using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns `Runid` and `type`.
I want to create a column result with following values.
if `runid='R1'` and `type==1.5` then result column should have value pass
and if `runid=='R2'` and `type==1` then result column should have value fail.

Pleas help with corresponding pandas code.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have only two conditions:

```
def result(runid, typ):
    if runid == "R1" and typ == 1.5:
        return "PASS"
    else: # add condition here if needed
        return "FAIL"

df["result"] = df.apply(lambda x: result(x.runid, x.type), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`numpy.where`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to create a new column based on nested conditionals.

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'runid': ['R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R2'],
                  'type': [1, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1.5, 1]})

df['result_column'] = np.where(df['runid'].eq('R1') & df['type'].eq(1.5), 'pass', \
                                  np.where(df['runid'].eq('R2') & df['type'].eq(1), 'fail', ''))
```

##### `>>> print(df)`

[image]

*If necessary, you can add more conditions to categorize the other combinations of values.*